# SBT AutoPlugin dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I've created an SBT plugin placed into project folder. This plugin extends `sbt.AutoPlugin` and adds a custom task.

Something like this:

```
object MyCustomTask extends AutoPlugin {
   ...
   lazy val myCustomTask = Def.task {
      runner.value.run("my.support.project.classpath.Utility")
   }
}
```

and I have this `build.sbt`

```
lazy val support = (project in file("support"))
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.197"
  ))

lazy val root = (project in file("root"))
  .settings(...)
  .dependsOn(support) // <- how can I remove this?
  .enablePlugin(MyCustomTask)
```

I don't want to make a dependency between `root` project and `support` project, because in this way `root` inherits all the dependecies from `support` that it doesn't needs (like the `h2database` dependency), but if I remove the `dependsOn(support)` the task defined in `MyCustomTask` can't find `my.support.project.classpath.Utility`.

Ho can I move that dependency into `MyCustomTask` plugin definition?

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies can be added to the plugin overriding the `projectSettings` field, like the following:

```
object MyCustomTask extends AutoPlugin {
  ...
  lazy val myCustomTask = Def.task {
    runner.value.run("my.support.project.classpath.Utility")
  }

  override val projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.197"
  )
}
```